# ASP.NET CORE Web App throwing SQLiteException: unable to open database file

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, sqlite

I have an SQLite DB and I uploaded it to my server [hosted in azure]. But when I try to access it, It throws `SQLiteException: unable to open database file`.

My connection string is something like this -

`string connectionString = "Data Source=https:\\mywebsite.azurewebsites.net\\DB\\persondb.db; Version=3"`

I also tried this too -

`string connectionString = "Data Source=~/DB/persondb.db; Version=3";`

Here is my full method's code -

```
        public static List<PersonDetails> GetPersons()
        {
            // string connectionString = "Data Source=https:\\mywebsite.com\\DB\\persondb.db; Version=3";
            string connectionString = "Data Source=~/DB/persondb.db; Version=3";

            using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
            {
                var output = cnn.Query<PersonDetails>
                    ("SELECT * FROM persons",
                    new DynamicParameters());
                return output.ToList();
            }
        }
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: The connection string is wrong It should be a local path rather than URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jack Jia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10223674/jack-jia)'s answer clears the scenario. But since `Server.MapPath` doesn't work in ASP.NET Core, we can get the server root path via `IWebHostEnvironment`interface.

This problem can be resolved like this -

1. Create a string that can be accessed globally 
   [e.g. `internal static string rootpath;`]
2. In `startup.cs` file, assign `rootpath` in the method 
   `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)` 
   [e.g. `Program.rootpath = env.WebRootPath;`]
3. Now a valid connection string should look like this - 
   `string connectionString = $"Data Source={Program.rootpath}/DB/demo.db; Version=3";`

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [About SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/about.html)

> SQLite is an embedded SQL database engine. Unlike most other SQL
>   databases, SQLite does not have a separate server process. SQLite
>   reads and writes directly to ordinary disk files.

You may use the following code in your ASP.NET web project:

```
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/DB");
    string connectionString = $"Data Source={path}/demo.db; Version=3";

    using (var con = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
    {
        con.Open();
        var cmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT SQLITE_VERSION()", con);
        return cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    }
```

The code `Server.MapPath("~/DB")` will find the physical path of the `DB` folder in your project, and then the connection string should be work.

Comment: Hi! Your answer clears something but It actually isn't correct. Server.MapPath doesn't work in ASP.NET Core. `IWebHostEnvironment` can be used as an alternative. Thanks, BTW.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me .Net 6

**Program.cs**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var services = builder.Services;
GlobalContext.ApplicationRootPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)??"";
```

**appSettings.json**

```
"DefaultConnection": "DataSource={dbPath}\\SqlLite\\app.db;Cache=Shared",
```

**Usage:**

```
var connectionString = connectionString.Replace("{dbPath}", GlobalContext.ApplicationRootPath);
                    options.UseSqlite(connectionString, sqlLiteOptions =>
                    {
                        sqlLiteOptions.MigrationsAssembly("MyAssembly");
                    });
```